# Uber API OAuth on watchOS 6.2 using ASWebAuthenticationSession

Tags: uber-api, watchos

I'm trying to authenticate with Uber's API using watchOS 6.2's new OAuth capability `ASWebAuthenticationSession`:

```
ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: uberUrl, callbackURLScheme: scheme) { (URL?, Error?) -> in {
  print(callbackUrl, error)

  if let url = callbackUrl {
     let components = NSURLComponents(string: (url.absoluteString))
     if let t = components?.queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "code"}).first?.value {
        self.token = t
     }
  }

  }
```

When I run it, an adorable little web browser comes up on the Watch and prompts for a "E-mail or Mobile Number", after entering my e-mail, clicking on "Next" pops up a text entry window which then suddenly disappears, leaving me back at e-mail entry.  The subsequent clicks on "Next" brings up a text entry window which only allows me to edit the e-mail address.  Password is never an option.  I never got the closure to complete, not even with en error.

If I scroll down to "Login with Google", then Google's login page loads, and lets me enter e-mail and password, and the completion block executes (I get a nil token presumably because my Uber account is not a Google one).

I suspect an issue with Uber's login webpage, but can't verify that other than observing that Google's seems to work.  Also, I can find no documentation on the `callbackURLScheme` parameter with respect to watchOS.  I create a scheme in the plist as one might with an iOS app, but can't confirm this is the correct procedure. Nonetheless, it doesn't change the fact that the password field will not come up on Uber's oath login page.

Searching StackOverflow for watchOS and ASWebAuthenticationSession produces no results at this point.

Is anyone else trying to do this right now?  Has anyone had success?  Am I missing something important, or is this simply an error on Uber's part?

Comment: Looks like it might be the CAPTCHA not working in the watchOS browser, preventing the next button from working...

Comment: It looks like the CAPTCHA has been removed form the Uber login page, and now I can get through to entering a password and even a code sent via SMS, but ASWebAuthenticationSession still doesn't complete and the Uber page resets to the first login page.

Comment: How do you create the info.plist for watchOS app? I find a new watch os app project do not have .plist file.